# Why is my Div being off-set to the right instead of centered?

Tags: css, html, css-position, positioning

I'm not quite sure why, but i cannot for the life of me figure out why my div is offset to the right. I'm still a little confused on positioning so i may have made an error there.

Here's the code i have on my container div:

```
#box{
     padding: 5px;
     margin-left:auto;
}
```

If you take a look at the Fiddle i posted below you'll notice that there is more space on the left than the right. If you don't see it, try expanding the preview window. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/Ya6A3/1/

Comment: .large has a margin-left of 25px and position absolute, so try without absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the element `.large` was being absolutely positioned.

You would remove `position:absolute` from the element and add `vertical-align:top` to fix vertical alignment issues. It's worth noting that an absolutely positioned element is essentially taken out of the flow and doesn't take other element's position into consideration. The element was thus positioned relative to the box's containing block

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pZ28/)

```
.large {
    margin-left: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 2px solid;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.4;
    height: 42em;
    width: 30em;
    padding: 0;
}
```